# Can I set the default number of vertices for a cylinder?

Tags: mesh

Is there any way to set the default number of vertices for a cylinder?
Every time I create one I get 32 as default but I usualy work with low poly models so I want it to be something like 8.
How to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

**Add** a cylinder then look at the **Last Operarotor** panel at the very bottom of the **Tool** panel you will find options for the new cylinder.

[image]

Secocnd option:
**Add** a cylinder then hit the **F6** key, a popup panel will appear. Here you will find the same options.

[image]

Comment: how this answers on how to set DEFAULT vertices count?

Comment: @m.ardito, good point . I should read a question twice before posting an answer :) .

Comment: Interestingly, followed the comment of the question, I was able to override the default setting for Cylinder, Circle and UV Sphere.  But following the same principle, trying to import the class for Torus and Cone returns some errors.